# Headers in Azure Data Factory HTTP Copy data source

Tags: http-headers, azure-data-factory

We are using Azure Data Factory to source data from an On-Premise JIRA installation. I've managed to get a number of pipelines to work using the JIRA API, but am hitting a wall when trying to source the Organization object.

There's an undocumented API call that can be made, though:

```
<servername>/jira/rest/servicedeskapi/organization
```

This will display the following message when attempting to run from a browser:

> "This API is experimental.  Experimental APIs are not guaranteed to be stable within the preview period. You must set the header 'X-ExperimentalApi: opt-in' to opt into using this API."

Using Postman, I set things up with the additional header, and I manage to get a resultset:

[image: PostMan example]

Using the same ADF copy data job I used for all my other API Calls, however, does not seem to work. I'm using the "Additional Headers" field to add a Bearer token we retrieve from our keyvault, like so:

```
@{concat(
    'Authorization: Bearer '
    , activity('Get Bearer token from Keyvault').output.value
)}
```

This works fine for all other API calls. I figured adding the extra header would be as simple as simply appending another line like so:

```
@{concat(
        'Authorization: Bearer '
        , activity('Get Bearer token from Keyvault').output.value,  
        ', X-ExperimentalApi: opt-in')
}
```

However, that ends up throwing an error:

> "ErrorCode=UserErrorInvalidHttpRequestHeaderFormat,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Failed
> to set addtional http
> header,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.ArgumentException,Message=Specified
> value has invalid HTTP Header characters.
> Parameter name: name,Source=System,'"

I tried wrapping double quotes (and escaping them) around the key/value pairs, but that did not work. I tried removing the comma, but somehow that leads to the REST API thinking the extra header is part of the Bearer token, as it then throws an "Unauthorized" exception.

I can get the API to return data if I use a WEB component without any issues, but it'd be nice if I somehow would get this to work within the Copy data activity.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The approaches that are tried to achieve this might be the incorrect way to provide multiple headers while using copy data activity.
- I have used `HTTP` source with a sample URL which accepts `Authorization: Bearer` token. However, giving additional header (even though it is not required) is working same as using just `Authorization` header.
- To pass multiple headers, pass each header separated by a **new line**.  I have used the dynamic content with string interpolation (`@{...}`), instead of using `@concat`.

```
Authorization: Bearer @{pipeline().parameters.token}
X-ExperimentalApi: opt-in
```

[image]

- You can see the following debug input how the additional headers are passed.

[image]

- As an alternative, since there are only 2 headers to be given, you can configure the `Authorization` in the linked service itself and use the `X-ExperimentalApi` as a single additional header in `Additional Headers` section of the copy data activity.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I never knew it was possible to just parse strings like that (hence option to use concat). But that seems to have done the trick just nicely.

Comment: I think the part where Microsoft blew it is that you cannot use dynamic content on the linked service and why would they not just do the additional headers in the HTTP copy like it is in the Rest copy. Go figure